# Why wont this email me a notification

Tags: php

Hi I've just got this video uploader form up and running and it works just fine. However I want some sort of notification to my email to let me know that someone has just uplaoded a video to my server. But it isn't notifying me I have totally simplified it just to get some sort of message to me but its just not functioning what have I missed?`

```
if(isset($_FILES["FileInput"]) && $_FILES["FileInput"]["error"]== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{

$UploadDirectory    = '../video_uploader/uploads/';


if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
    die();
}


//Is file size is less than allowed size.
if ($_FILES["FileInput"]["size"] > 500242880) {
    die("File size is too big!");
}

//allowed file type Server side check
switch(strtolower($_FILES['FileInput']['type']))
    {
        //allowed file types
        case 'image/png': 
        case 'image/gif': 
        case 'image/jpeg': 
        case 'image/pjpeg':
        case 'text/plain':
        case 'text/html': //html file
        case 'application/x-zip-compressed':
        case 'application/pdf':
        case 'application/msword':
        case 'application/vnd.ms-excel':
        case 'video/mp4':
            break;
        default:
            die('Unsupported File!'); //output error
}

$File_Name          = strtolower($_FILES['FileInput']['name']);
$File_Ext           = substr($File_Name, strrpos($File_Name, '.')); 
$Random_Number      = rand(0, 9999999999); //Random number to be added to name.
$NewFileName        = $Random_Number.$File_Ext; //new file name

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FileInput']['tmp_name'], $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName   ))
   {
    die('Success! File Uploaded.');
}else{
    die('error uploading File!');
}

}
else
{
die('Something wrong with upload! Is "upload_max_filesize" set correctly?');
}


mail("me@myemail.com.", $NewFileName);





?>`
```

Comment: [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) needs at least 3 parameters: `string $to , string $subject , string $message` ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this.changes the fields according to your needs.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "To: me@myemail.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: demo.com <contact@demo.com>" . "\r\n";

mail('me@myemail.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
// subject and message just choose according to your needs and it should be in html format.
```

for further reference follow these links

```
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mail.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not how php mailer works. It needs headers, a subject and a message. Without the proper headers the email won't send because it doesn't know were to go. Also, when you have everything setup: "check your spambox"

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mail.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: OK thanks I couldn't get it working with headers either I'll take another look after I've fixed the suggestion below

Answer (score 0):

Check your code again in this section:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FileInput']['tmp_name'], $UploadDirectory.$NewFileName   ))    
{
        die('Success! File Uploaded.'); 
}
else
{
        die('error uploading File!'); 
}
```

So, if your file is failed to upload, your script dies die() with an error message.
If on the other hand your upload succeeds, your scripts dies die() again.
Is this sounds logical to you? Your script never gets to the point where it should send an email.

Also, mail() function needs 3 parameters, as others have suggested.

Comment: Yes it was the die that was causing all the problems changed to echo and all is good thanks everyone